# Flutter switch button not activated using Riverpod

Tags: flutter, widget, switch-statement

I am employing Riverpod for state management via StateNotifierProvider. My switch button just won't enable upon clicking and thus no state changes to effect theme mode switching. I have spent a ton of hours researching similar issues but none like mine as I am not using setState(). I expect the state of the button to change on clicking on dragging but the thumb of the switch just returns to its initial off position. Please help me with what I am doing wrong. Here are snapshots of my main.dart, home_screen.dart, and the theme controller notifier as I am unable to copy and paste my code correctly as advised with 4 spaces.

[image: theme_controler]

[image: home Screen with switch button defined in appbar]
[image: main.dart]
[image: app UI showing switch remains in default state]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `state` (not the `_isDark`variable) this way:

```
toggleTheme(bool value) {
  state = value;
  _safePrefs;
}
```

The image is not complete, so I can't see the use of `_isDark` variable (Probably nothing). But You shoul be fine now, at least updating the state.

Comment: thanks a million. It worked like a charm!